# Get token and user details after token is issued in controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.net Identity for token based authentication in my web api application. The problem is I have to **perform some operations after the token is generated** and the user is authenticated **and before the redirection to client** side occurs.

I have a login page which uses /token token authentication . Once the token is issued i need to keep the user and token values in a session. [this session will be  used to show online users.]

Client request

```
 $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                // Post username, password & the grant type to /token
                url: '/token',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    username: $('#txtUsername').val(),
                    password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
                    grant_type: 'password'
                }
});
```

Server side

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Login()
    {
     OnlineUsers user = new OnlineUsers();
     var users = (HttpContext.Current.Session["ActiveUsers"] as 
     List<OnlineUsers>) ?? new List<OnlineUsers>();
     users.Add(user);
     HttpContext.Current.Session["ActiveUsers"] = users;
    }
```

I need to call this controller method after the token is issued and use is authenticated.
Is there any solution to this?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: i have added the minimal description of what i want to achieve

Comment: You should provide some codes to show what you have tried...

Comment: codes are included

Answer (score 0):

If you want to intercept generation of the token  think you have to customize the aspnet identity behaviour

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.usermanagerextensions.generateusertoken(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 0):

With Web API using session is not a good approach, to keep user's information in client side you can use browser's localstorage. Once the user authenticated via your login api controller, you can return the user's required info as json to client, then you can keep it to browsers. Web API is by default stateless so i think session is not suitable with it, additional burden on the client. **Storing session state on the server violates the stateless constraint of the REST architecture. So the session state must be handled entirely by the client.**

**Web API**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResultLogin()
{
     OnlineUsers user = new OnlineUsers();
     user=YourUserDetailsMethod();
     return Ok(user);
}
```

**Client:**

```
$('#btnLogin').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            // Post username, password & the grant type to /token
            url: '/token',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                username: $('#txtUsername').val(),
                password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
                grant_type: 'password'
            },
            success: function(response){
                window.localStorage.setItem('userInfo', response);
                $('#UserName').val(window.localStorage.getItem('userInfo').UserName);
            }
});
```